# How to make second floated div to come on top of the first floated div?

Tags: css, html, css-float

I have two floated div in a wrapper. They are `left` and `right`. I wanted to make the right div to appear at the top of first div(left). Right should come first and left should come at second.

Here is the code

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">
        left
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        right
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#left{
    float:right;
    }
#right{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
#wrapper{
    width:100px;
   background-color: #000fff;
}
```

I'm looking to have the same 100% as width for right div. Is this possible without changing markup and doing changes in CSS alone?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uBjt2/)

**EDITED**
I want the right div to be in top and left should in bottom after that. When i use position absolute for the right div then left div is hidden. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uBjt2/3/).
Should look like this [image: Should look like this]

Comment: do you have a fixed height for .right div ?

Comment: NO. The right div may contain dynamic content so i don't have fixed height for it. It is auto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want place the right `div` before left, just remove the `float:left` property from `#right`.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uBjt2/1/)

If you want the right `DIV` **above** the left,  you need to use `absolute position`

Comment: i used position absolute but it hiding the left div. Check my edits

Comment: @sun you need to calculate the height of #right and assign the value as top margin of #left using jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/uBjt2/8/

Comment: Thanks for jquery suggestion

Answer (score 3):

Use the following css :

```
#left{
    float:right;
    border: 1px solid black;
    }
#right{
    float:left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}
#wrapper{
    width:100px;
   background-color: #000fff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks i used position absolute but the left div is hidden in this case. Check my edits

Comment: Thanks. +1 for using absolute position

Answer (score 2):

First of all clear the float, then set `position:relative` to the parent "wrapper" and `position:absolute;` to the right div.

Check out **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/uBjt2/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this with **just** css you have to use absolute positioning. But only if you know height of each element and exact number of elements like this. Check this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cemozer/nT8h6/)**.

Let's assume each element has 20px height, then you can place one at `top: 0px` and second at `top:20px`. And to use remaning space like usual relative way, you must add padding equals to total height of your elements that has absolute positioning to wrapper.

Alternatively you can use JavaScript to change order in html.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too convinced by the answers so far.  I would recommend avoiding 'absolute' and even javascript.  Also if you want to make it friendly to all browsers you should really be specifying things such as height.  It's a common misconception that a design can't be worked on every modern browser without huge hacks (i was doing it years ago for IE5.5 and firefox etc), its usually due to the CSS not being properly formed and valid. Now try the following:

```
 #left, #right {position:relative; float:left; height:30px;  color:white; width:inherit;   }

 #left{
 background-color:blue;
 margin-top:30px;
 }
 #right{
 background-color:green;
 margin-left:-100%;
 margin-top:0;
 }
 #wrapper{
 width:100px;
 background-color: #000fff;
 }
```